# R extract data by for loop

Tags: r

I have a large number of matrix, calls train which is a binary data with 1 and 0

I want to extract and make another two lists which contains 1 as list1 and 0 as list2 by using for loop

my R code is not working

```
X <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1)
Y <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0)
train<- as.matrix (cbind(X,Y))
list1 <- list()
list2 <- list()

for(i in 1:length(train)) {
 if(train[i]== 1)
    list1 = train[i]
 else
    list2 = train[i]

}
```

Therefore I want my list1 to contain (1,1,1,1,1,1,1) and list2 to contain (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/42674516/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't need a for loop, just select your data using a logical evaluation. By the way, the data structure you want in R is called `vector`, not `list`. Please refer to this website (http://www.programcreek.com/2014/01/vector-array-list-and-data-frame-in-r/) for more information.

```
list1 <- train[train == 1]
list2 <- train[train == 0]
```